# Redshift : AWS ds2.2xlarge vs AWS ds2.8xlarge : which one performs well for insert/update/delete operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-serverless

When performing and insert/update/delete operations or node replacement operation, which one amouung the AWS will perform faster : ds2.2xlarge  or ds2.8xlarge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several factors to consider when select a node type for Amazon Redshift:

- The amount of storage required
- The amount of CPU desired
- The ability to perform `COPY` statements in parallel
- Cost

A `ds2.8xlarge` offers approximately 8x the storage and compute as a `ds2.xlarge`. However, is also has 8x the cost. The `ds2.8xlarge` will certainly be faster and better, but the question is whether it is worth the extra cost.

The biggest reason to move to a larger node is to use more **storage**. You can either use multiple `ds2.xlarge` nodes or move up to a `ds2.8xlarge` node. If you do not require the storage, then it is harder to justify the cost of moving to a large node.

Sometimes, however, it can be worthwhile if it is a **transient cluster**, such as one that performs a specific job for a few hours and then terminates. This could be particularly useful for performing a complex load and transformation of data, which can take advantage of more parallelism.